# Upload to onedrive from winforms, one time login

Tags: c#, winforms, live-sdk, onedrive

I wish my winforms application to be able to upload to the current logged in user's onedrive account (win 8+). I found this
http://www.codeguru.com/columns/dotnet/authenticating-a-onedrive-account.html

but it seems that they are actually creating a web browser to log in, to grab a token, which then expires after an hour anyway. I don't mind having the user log in once, or very infrequently, but every hour is not acceptable. Ideally, I just want to be able to pull the current logged in user (linked window/MS account), and use their current credentials to access Live stuff (i.e. oneDrive).

Any ideas?

Thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

There are actually a few different SDK's available that will allow you to authenticate the user using OAuth 2.0.  You may want to look at the OneDrive API Explorer (http://onedrive.github.io/sample-code.htm).  You can also make a call using REST which is described at http://onedrive.github.io/auth/msa_oauth.htm which also describes how to refresh the access token.  I hope that helps.

Toan